# How do I get the units of an Algorand Standard Assets (ASA) automatically deposited into the reserve address?

Tags: algorand

I'm trying to create assets with a creator address into a reserve address. But if I create the asset all units are send to the creator address instead of the reserve address. How do I get all assets into the reserve address or is the reserve address pure for show?

Answer (score 0):

The reserve address is purely information ("for show").
Units are always created in the creator address.
If the reserve address is different, you then need to send an opt-in transactions from the reserve address, and then need to send all tokens to this address.